# Isset post and break for loop

Tags: php, javascript

I have this code below

```
for ($p=1; $p<30000; $p++) {

    if(isset($_POST['stop_loop'])) {
       break;
    }

    loop do something

}
```

My question is how stop the loop after I post stop_loop?

Maybe I should use die(); but I try and it doesn't work is there any way?
If not maybe Neal was right

Comment: Can you explain your intentions? As is, this code doesn't do what I think you expect it to do.

Answer (score 3):

You get all the post values at the start of the code.

So if that POST was there to begin with then the for loop will never execute.

**You cannot submit a post to an already executing php file**

Comment: You can, however, set a `$_POST` variable if it isn't already set, but it's probably not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Consider having some file acting as a semaphore. Then the for-loop you posted above would simply check for the existence of this file at every iteration. If it exists, stop the loop. Otherwise, continue processing.

For example, this pseudo code might work:

```
if "post variable" = "stop loop"
    create file "stop loop"
else
    while file "stop loop" does not exist
        do something
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems rather.. painful. Why not have

```
$stop_point = isset($_POST['stop_loop']) ? $_POST['stop_loop'] : 30000;

for ($p = 1; $p < $stop_point; $p++) {
    loop do something
}
```

instead? The POST value is set when the script starts up (and you've actually POSTed a form to this script), so the value of `$_POST['stop_loop']` will NOT change throughout the life of the script.

Answer (score 1):

If you set somewhere in "loop do something"

```
 $_POST['stop_loop'] = true;
```

it will break.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really feasible to approach this problem this way. You would need two scripts. One that runs the loop and one you post to.

In the first script, you should check for something existing ina  database or a flatfile.

The second script should make that item you are checking for.

For example:

script A checks for a file e.g. stopLoop.file
when you post stop to script B, it creates the file stopLoop.file

I wouldn't do it exactly this way as all those file checks will slow you script down quite a bit, but you get the idea here.